# How can I use "Font style" in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-preferences

The user needs to have the ability to change his system font through using my new application. So how can I get a port of "Font style" in my application from the preferences item which is located under "Settings -> Display -> Screen Display -> Font Style" ?

Also, I searched for "Font style" in the Android source code and wasn't able to find it.

Comment: You need to accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: How can I accept answers to my questions ?

Comment: Just click the checkmark to the left of the answer you consider to be the solution to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So how can I get a port of "Font style" in my application as preferences which is located "settings -> Display -> Screen display -> Font style" ?

That does not exist in standard Android. There is no system-wide "font style" setting. Your specific device might offer that setting, in which case it probably affects only the built-in apps.

Comment: I believe it's mostly a Samsung thing. It actually affects most apps (I believe it just replaces Droid Sans Regular, Italic, and Bold in the system folder) if they're not specifying their own styles.

Comment: @kcoppock: Ah, OK. That's actually rather scary -- there's no guarantee that the app will be readable in the other font. Bugs the crap out of me when device manufacturers pull stunts like this...

Comment: Yup, I definitely agree, and most of the defaults are Comic Sans-ish, which is worse. Some of them cause the "h" in "Bluetooth" in the status bar widget to wrap to another line (which looks atrocious).